# Jetpack Compose GoogleMap know offline state

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I have set the `GoogleMap` on Jetpack compose.

```
    GoogleMap(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        uiSettings = uiSettings,
    )
```

I can see the GoogleMap loads even the device is offline. I searched about the max age of caching period but got this:

```
The exact duration for which Google Maps caches map tiles on a device isn't publicly disclosed by Google.
```

Anyone know how can I know the Google map is loading or not from cache?
My use case scenario is if the Google map is not loading offline I want to hide it from the app.

Comment: Why not just check the connectivity of the device and decide based on that?

Comment: My requirement is to check the Google map offline state.

Comment: the `GoogleMap` composable function has this `onMapLoaded` prop though I'm not sure if this is not fired when offline. ref: https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-google-map.html